# Flow of $rot \overrightarrow{F}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

We've got vector field: $\overrightarrow{F} = \begin{bmatrix} yz\\x^3z\\e^z\end{bmatrix}$. I want to compute flow of $rot\overrightarrow{F} $($=curl \overrightarrow{F}$) through the area of the side of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$, between surfaces: $z=5$ and $2x+y+z=2$, in the direction from (not towards) coordinate $z$. 
So, how to compute it? Let $C$ be the curve {$x^2 +y^2=1; z<5, 2x+y+z>2$} and $D$ be the domain bounded by curve C (so $D =${$x^2+y^2<1, 2-2x-y<z<5$}). But I guess I need to give a parametric representation of $D$ (in order to find a normal vector $\overrightarrow{n}$) and then check if my parametric representation is correct. How to do it? Cause then I will write $rot \overrightarrow{F}$ which is easy to compute and all I will be looking for is $\int\limits_D  rot \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \overrightarrow{n} d S$. So my major diificulty is how to find parametric representation of $D$ (which will give me $\overrightarrow{n}$ and check if it is correct. Can you help me?

Comment: You're confusing curves and surfaces here. $S$ is the part of the cylinder you described. You can parametrize it (by $\theta$ and $z$ in a certain region), or you can apply Stokes's Theorem to compute a line integral.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Anyway- can you tell me how to parametrize it?

Comment: Well I made it : $x=cos(a), y=sin(a), z=z$. But how to check if it is correct?

Comment: That's correct, although I would write $a=\theta$, since $a$ looks constant to me. Now what region in $(\theta,z)$ space gives you your surface? (Note that $z=5$ and $2x+y+z=2$ intersect OUTSIDE the cylinder.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: As @Ted noted you will have $$C: \mathbf{r(t)}=\big(\cos(\theta),~\sin(\theta),~~2-2\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)\big),~~~~0\le\theta\le2\pi$$ Now evaluate $$\oint_C F\cdot dr$$

[image]

Comment: Be careful here. The boundary of her surface $S$ has two components to it, the ellipse in the plane $2x+y+z=2$ *and* the circle in the plane $z=5$. We also have to pay attention to which direction to proceed around each of these curves.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I really considered the ellipse below. is there a serious defect in the hint, Ted?

Comment: It's a great hint, but I worry that the OP might miss the other curve and the orientation issues.

Comment: So I have a queston- in Stoke's theorem we have curve oriented in such way that if we look at the manifold from the positive, we see the anticlockwise circulation. And the only thing I am given is that orientation is from coordinate z. What about it?

Comment: @Anne: What is the direction of the Flow? $\uparrow$ or $\downarrow$. I assume the $z$ direction up,as usual.

Comment: Awesome! + 1, dear friend!