# What does "$\operatorname{rot}[\vec{a} \times \vec{b}]$" mean? (from an article written in the $60$s)

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vector-analysis

I saw in old article written in $60$'s a mathematical expression

$$\operatorname{rot}[\vec{a} \times \vec{b}]$$

What is the function of $\operatorname{rot}$ and what it means?

[image: see the image here]

Comment: I think you'll probably have to give a bit more context to get an answer. can you give the name of the article (or, even better, link to an open access version of it)? what was the context in the paper in which you came across this expression?

Comment: I suspect it is an alternative term for *the curl of a 3D vectorfield*. In many languages that is called "rotation", "roottori", "rotacion", etc. Check out the *languages* section of the relevant [WP-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4138654/1072645, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/395596/1072645

Comment: @BeKind's comment is helpful in linking to questions that discuss two completely different meanings. Please update your question so we can say which definition if either is applicable.

Comment: Using rot for curl is also found in "older" English-language texts.  Note that, even today, a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ with $\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{0}$ is said to be "irrotational".

Comment: The important question is this: are $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ *vector fields* or fixed vectors?

Comment: It is more likely curl of vector/matrix.  But this is the first time I heard of rot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe slipped through from a german text where "rot" stands for "rotation" or "rotor".  The english term is "curl":

$$\operatorname{rot}[a\times b] = \nabla\times(a\times b)$$

Comment: "Rot" is no longer common in English, but [it's not unheard of](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=rot+curl).  The Wikipedia article mentions it in paragraph 3.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at your equation it appears to be a [Lorentz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) with the force on a charged particle of charge $Q$ in some kind of radial magnetic field $H_\mu$ with a [magnetic vector potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential) of $\vec{\mu}\times\vec{r}/r^3$, and the mysterious "rot" would just be the usual curl of the magnetic field, $H=\nabla \times A$, where $A$ is the magnetic vector potential.